# How to use Column.isin in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter a Spark DataFrame using a list in Java.

```
java.util.List<Long> selected = ....;
DataFrame result = df.filter(df.col("something").isin(????));
```

The problem is that `isin(...)` method accepts Scala `Seq` or varargs.

Passing in `JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(selected)` doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `stream` method as follows:

```
df.filter(col("something").isin(selected.stream().toArray(String[]::new))))
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter version would be:

```
df.filter(col("something").isin(selected.toArray()));
```