# : _* notation in scala

Tags: scala

I am encountering this : _* notation in many spark-scala answers, but couldn't find any documentation. What does it mean actually? An example of such usage is in the answer to this question

[How to use DataFrame filter with isin in Spark Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468776/how-to-use-dataframe-filter-with-isin-in-spark-java)

line:

```
df.filter(col("something").isin(list: _*)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass Scala array into Scala vararg method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064753/how-to-pass-scala-array-into-scala-vararg-method) or [What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala)

Comment: @pasternak : please see/check whether same kind of question was asked, which has answers... before you raise new question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To understand it, lets take an example

```
scala> def echo(args: String*) =
for (arg <- args) println(arg)
echo: (args: String*)Unit

scala>  val arr = Array("What's", "up", "doc?")
arr: Array[String] = Array(What's, up, doc?)

scala> echo(arr)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[String]
 required: String
       echo(arr)
scala> echo(arr: _ *)
What's
up
doc?
```

This notation,`arr:_*` tells the compiler to pass each element of arr as its own argument to `echo` , rather than all of it as a single argument.